# How to make a board key act like the right mouse key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, xmodmap, menu

As most keyboard these days come with no *Menu-key* it would be nice to set a key to the operation of the right mouse button. So far I still have to select text. 
How could I get the board key act like the right mouse key with **opening the context menu *just* upon hovering?**

To find the key code of anything to press using

```
$ xev
```

Assigning any key to the `Menu` function to e.g. the `Alt-right` key:

```
$ xmodmap -e 'keycode 108 = menu'
```

[Credit where credit due](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167088/keyboard-shortcut-equivalent-to-right-clicking), here its to [Grumbel](https://askubuntu.com/users/4547/grumbel).

Now this works great and I can open the `Menu` at any position. However, "the Menu" is now the `Menu` of an open window, e.g. firefox. 
So I have to mark a word or text phrase to open the menu on that context (word), like a link or text in a writing GUI for which I would like to use the available spelling correction.

How could I make the key stroke to open the context menu when just hovering over it?

I am using Arch Linux kernel v5.5.10. and the suckless dwm v6.2 on a Thinkpad T470p.

Comment: Shift+F10 doesn't work?

Comment: `Shift`+`F10` are the same as assigning `Menu` to a keycode. Howering over a word is not enough to lunch the context menu. I still need to put the courser there with some sort of *click* or mark.